# Why does the the Artemis I translunar flight (have to) last 6 days while the Apollo fights to the Moon lasted only about 3 days?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, station-keeping, artemis-program

Does the Artemis I flight to the Moon have to last so long compared to the about 3 days long lasting Apollo flights because the Orion spacecraft has to enter into a [distant retrograde orbit (DRO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distant_retrograde_orbit#) ?
Or will it just travel slower to save rocket fuel ?

Comment: This certainly is a duplicate of the linked question. Neither the Apollo flights nor that of Artemis 1 are Hohmann transfers. The goals are different. Apollo needed to do it quickly (compared to a Hohmann transfer) because of life support and electrical constraints. Artemis 1 is doing it slowly (compared to a Hohmann transfer) because the goal is to get a bigger gravity assist / Oberth effect from the Moon for the purpose of easing a later injection into a distant retrograde lunar orbit.

Comment: @DavidHammen  I think you're right, thanks for redirecting me.